# Get link from url and get email by regex

Tags: java, regex, url

I'm looking for good regex in java to get string url from all links and all emails. Now I have regex for links:

```
 String linkRegex = "http[s]*://(\\w+\\.)*(\\w+)";
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(linkRegex);

   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(stringAddres);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            String currentLink = matcher.group();
}
```

and I got links like: `http://twitter.com` but also I have `https://google`. So is there any way that I can remove links like `https://google`?

And I need regex that gives me email from string, for example: 
from this:

```
href="mailto:contact@example.com">contact@example.com</a></span>
```

I should get only contact@example.com

Comment: Where did you find your actual `linkRegex`? Furthermore, there are already a ton of questions about "regex for xxx", http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=regex+for+email+%5Bjava%5D or http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=regex+for+url+%5Bjava%5D so..

Comment: It work only for contact@example.com and similar but when i have email like this: contact.us@example.com it give me only us@example.com

Comment: How about: `[\w.]+@\w+?(\.\w+)+`? Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/BiDw0t/4)

Comment: this [\w.]+@\w+?(\.\w+)+ don't give me any email i don't know why, but your previous regex after some modifications work, but i don't know that work for all emails or only for :xxx.xxx@xxx.xxx. this is the regex : \\w+\\.\\w+@\\w+?\\.\\w{2,3} but it doesn't work for xxx.xxx@xxx.xxx.xxx

Comment: Okey i find regex which works: [_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})". So any idea for links?

Answer (score 0):

There are many answered questions with simple regex patterns that work with most common mails, still I would suggest this regex based on RFC 5322 Standard:

> (?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:a-z0-9?.)+a-z0-9?|[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)])

Copied from [this site](http://emailregex.com/).

Comment: do you know why i have error when i copied regex for java to eclipse and what is wrong ? `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])");`  I have invalid escape sequence

Comment: Sorry I didn't see when I pasted code, because ` is used for formatting comments it didn't copy properly, I have edited now.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use look-behind to lock onto the interesting attributes in the text, and then just capture everything in the "...".

Like this

```
((?<=href="mailto:)|(?<=src="))[^"]+
```